# Resetting / Updating TTL for a Couchbase counter

Tags: python, couchbase

(This is a pretty simple question - one that can be answered by trying out - but since the docs are not explicit about it, I figured I'd document it here)

When I set a new TTL'd couchbase counter (using incr() in python, for example) - and then re-incr() the counter with *another* TTL value, would the key's TTL be reset to the new value?

here's another way of asking this:

if I run the following code:

```
cb.incr(key='mykey',amount=1,initial=1,ttl=10) //10 seconds TTL
cb.incr(key='mykey',amount=1,initial=1,ttl=100) //will this update the TTL?
```

will the key expire after 10 or 100 seconds?

The python library docs: http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client-1.2.3/api/couchbase.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a second `incr` operation does *not* update the TTL. If you do want to change the TTL use the `touch` command.

Note this matches the behaviour of the original memcached protocol - see for example [How does incr work with expiry times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890682/how-does-incr-work-with-expiry-times)

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is no: the 2nd call to incr() does not update the TTL, but will successfully increment the counter.

Rather confusingly, this is NOT true for the .set() API (or upsert() API). for example, the following code

```
print cb.set('hello',{'hi':'there'},ttl=1)
print cb.set('hello',{'hi':'there'})
```

will result with a non-TTL'd doc -  The 2nd call to set() removes the TTL.